# How to connect programmatically to an embedded HornetQ server

Tags: java, osgi, hornetq

I'm running an embedded HornetQ server on an OSGI container following an example for embedded HornetQ Core.

I have three OSGI containers: one for the server, one for a producer and a last one for a consumer. Everything works on local.

The code I'm using in both the producer and consumer for connecting to the server is the following:

```
// Step 4. As we are not using a JNDI environment we instantiate the objects directly
ServerLocator serverLocator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName()));
ClientSessionFactory sf = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();
```

I've tried looking at the `TransportConfiguration` methods, but no setter was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass parameters to the Transport configuration:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("port", org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.TransportConstants
                      .DEFAULT_PORT);
parameters.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, "127.0.0.1");

TransportConfiguration configuration = new TransportConfiguration(
        NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), parameters);
```

Notice you have / could do the same to the `NettyAcceptor`. I'm not sure how you are configuring the acceptors at your test.. but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I'm not configuring the acceptors at all . Currently I'm just fiddling a bit with HornetQ while a co-worker does the same with ActiveMQ so we can compare them. I'll try the answer and come back later to accept it.

Comment: Since you accept the answer I take it that it solved your issue.
Let me know if you have any issues. either here or the HornetQ user's forum

Comment: Yes, my issue was solved, thank you. I'm also quite sure we're going to use HornetQ in our proyect so more questions will appear in the near future.